# Swift: Two tabelView in scroll view

Tags: swift

I use Xcode 8.0 with swift 2.3.

I have a scrollView, and I want to use segment to control page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkzg2.jpg

There are two tableView in the scrolView

But it is error in the function:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

> Contstant 'cell' used before being initialized

this is error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTN4R.jpg

This is initialize 'cell', right?

```
 let cell:UITableViewCell?
```

above is my code

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate  {
@IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl2: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var recipesImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!
@IBOutlet var tableView1:UITableView!
var recipes:Recipe!
var noodles:Recipe!
var snacks:Recipe!
var category: Int = Int()

@IBAction func segmented(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:0, y:0), animated: true)
        case 1:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:375, y:0), animated: true)
        case 2:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:750, y:0), animated: true)
        case 3:
            scroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:1125, y:0), animated: true)


        default:
            print()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    switch self.category {
        case 0:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipes.image)
            title = self.recipes.name
        case 1:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodles.image)
            title = self.noodles.name
        case 2:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: snacks.image)
            title = self.snacks.name
        case 3:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodles.image)
            title = self.noodles.name
        case 4:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: noodles.image)
            title = self.noodles.name
        default:
            self.recipesImageView.image = UIImage(named: recipes.image)
            title = self.recipes.name
    }

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

    //刪除多餘的隔線
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red: 240.0/255.0, green: 240.0/255.0, blue: 240.0/255.0, alpha: 1)

    //title = self.recipes.name

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 36.0;
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    tableView1.dataSource = self
    tableView1.delegate = self
    tableView1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var cellNum:Int?
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        cellNum = 4
        //return cellNum
    }

    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
        cellNum = 1
    }
    return cellNum!
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView == self.tableView {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell
        //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        if self.category == 0 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
                cell.valueLabel.text = recipes.name
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 1:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
                cell.valueLabel.text = recipes.type
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 2:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
                cell.valueLabel.text = (recipes.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 3:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
                cell.valueLabel.text = recipes.material
                cell.amountLabel.text = recipes.amount
            default:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
                cell.valueLabel.text = ""
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""
            }
        }

        if self.category == 1 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.name
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 1:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.type
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 2:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
                cell.valueLabel.text = (noodles.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 3:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.material
                cell.amountLabel.text = noodles.amount
            default:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
                cell.valueLabel.text = ""
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""
            }
        }

        if self.category == 2 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
                cell.valueLabel.text = snacks.name
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 1:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
                cell.valueLabel.text = snacks.type
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 2:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
                cell.valueLabel.text = (snacks.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 3:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
                cell.valueLabel.text = snacks.material
                cell.amountLabel.text = snacks.amount
            default:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
                cell.valueLabel.text = ""
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""
            }
        }

        if self.category == 3 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.name
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 1:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.type
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 2:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
                cell.valueLabel.text = (noodles.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 3:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.material
                cell.amountLabel.text = noodles.amount
            default:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
                cell.valueLabel.text = ""
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""
            }
        }

        if self.category == 4 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "名稱"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.name
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 1:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "類型"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.type
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 2:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "收藏"
                cell.valueLabel.text = (noodles.isFavor) ? "Yes" : "No"
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""

            case 3:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = "食材"
                cell.valueLabel.text = noodles.material
                cell.amountLabel.text = noodles.amount
            default:
                cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
                cell.valueLabel.text = ""
                cell.amountLabel.text = ""
            }
        }
            //return cell
    }

    if tableView == self.tableView1 {
           let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell

        if self.category == 0 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = recipes.material
            default:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = recipes.material
            }
        }
        if self.category == 1 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = noodles.material
            default:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = noodles.material
            }
        }
        if self.category == 2 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = snacks.material
            default:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = snacks.material
            }
        }
        if self.category == 3 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = noodles.material
            default:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = noodles.material
            }
        }
        if self.category == 4 {
            switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = noodles.material
            default:
                cell.materialLabel!.text = noodles.material
            }
        }
    }

    return cell   //<----This line will error ***********************
}


//避免被前面一頁的隱藏導覽列所影響
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = false
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}

/*
 // MARK: - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
 // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 }
 */
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe these changes should help:

1. Change `let cell:UITableViewCell?` to `let cell:UITableViewCell`. The function doesn't want you to return an optional.
2. Change `let cell = tableView.dequeue...` to `cell = tableView.dequeue...`. You shouldn't declare `cell` twice.
3. Update structure within `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to this:

`if tableView == self.tableView {
    cell = ...
    ...
} else {
    cell = ...
    ...
}
return cell`

So the compiler will see you're always setting cell to something before returning it.

Comment: Thaks. But It's stiil doesn't work,and I think "var cell: UITableViewCell" should turn to "var cell: DetailTableViewCell" will be better

Comment: This is my project, I hope you can help me! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxR-yfmaqz48cEJkLUs0ZlY0OFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You should use `var` and set to `nil`. Then also don't re-initialize inside your if-else condition.

```
var cell: UITableViewCell? = nil

if tableView == self.tableView {
    cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell

    // other lines of codes
}
if tableView == self.tableView1 {
    cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell

    // other lines of codes
}
```

Comment: It's stiil work,I think "var cell: UITableViewCell" should turn to "var cell: DetailTableViewCell"

Comment: If so, then return inside the if condition itself. And return nil at last line of function

Comment: return nil will error: nil is incompatible with return type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: sorry i mean return UITableViewCell()

Comment: cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell1",    forIndexPath: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell<-------this line cause "thread 1: breakpoint 3.1"

Comment: you should use the same identifier define in your cell in storyboard

Comment: I am sure the identifier are the same.Please check my projecthttps://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxR-yfmaqz48cEJkLUs0ZlY0OFU/view  Sorry, I don't know how to push my proiect to the gitHub

Comment: but in your code above, the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` using different string for identifier, but using the same class

Comment: cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? DetailTableViewCell <-----this line is wrong?